# Need help in Qliksense vlookup function

Tags: qliksense

I have two excel files, where I have to pull certain columns from one excel based on the matching id in from another excel.

I have across a discussion in qliksense community (https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-App-Dev/VLookup/td-p/1068404), I have tried the suggested solution, but I am still getting "Field not found" error while running the script. Below is the script which I am trying to run

```
Master:
LOAD
    "Department Name",
    "Financial Department Number",
    "Lead1 Contact",
    "Lead2  Contact",
    "Lead3 Contact",
FROM [lib://tech/Department Master_old.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is [Department Master]);

RawData:
LOAD
    Idea_ID,
    Idea_Title,
    Created_Date,
    Created_By,
    People_Leader,
    Lookup("Lead1  Contact","Lead3 Contact",H_People_Leader,"[Department Master]"),
    Description,
    Comments,
FROM [lib://tech/Raw Report.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet5);
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
Field 'Lead1  Contact' not found
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: the table to look is called `Master` and not `[Department Master]`?

Comment: Replacing double quotes(") with single quote(') in vlookup solved the issue, posted solution in my question , as I couldn't format it properly in comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** This solution worked for me

```
Master:
LOAD
    "Department Name",
    "Financial Department Number",
    "Lead1 Contact",
    "Lead2  Contact",
    "Lead3 Contact",
FROM [lib://tech/Department Master_old.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is [Department Master]);

RawData:
LOAD
    Idea_ID,
    Idea_Title,
    Created_Date,
    Created_By,
    People_Leader,
    Lookup('Lead1  Contact','Lead3 Contact',H_People_Leader,'[Department Master]'),
    Description,
    Comments,
FROM [lib://tech/Raw Report.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet5)
```

Note : Just replaced double quotes(") with a single quote(') in lookup function.